# Insert a script tag inside template Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a integration with a **payment service**.
The payment service provides me a **form** with a script tag inside, I want to insert that form with script tag inside my component template, 
but vue doesn't allow the insertion of tag script within a template, how can I insert that form with script tag inside my template component?

the form with checkout of **payment service**:

```
    <form action="http://localhost:8081/api/v1/payment/" method="POST">
      <script
        src="https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js"
        data-public-key="KEY"
        data-transaction-amount="14.90">
      </script>
    </form>
```

The expected result:
My component:

```
<template>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <form action="http://localhost:8081/api/v1/payment/" method="POST">
            <script
                src="https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js"
                data-public-key="KEY"
                data-transaction-amount="14.90">
            </script>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {}
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an element reference and vanilla JS to add the relevant tag to the dom.

```
<form ref="myform">
  ...
</form>

mounted() {
  let foo = document.createElement('script');    
  foo.setAttribute("src","https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js");
  foo.setAttribute("data-transaction-amount", "14.90")
  this.$refs.myform.appendChild(foo);
}
```

Comment: Hey! In this scenario, would it be possible to pass props via script tag?
I'm injecting some micro front-ends junks inside my main Vue app by script tag and I'd like to send some props to these small apps. Something like this:

index.html file inside my Vue main app:

<script src= "micro-front-host-url"><script>

Tag container inside my Vue main app (where my micro front is rendered once it's loaded):

<div id="my-micro"  :myProp = "somePropFromMainApp"></div>

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but I came across with this problem with MercadoPago and TommyF's answer really solved it. But in my case the data-transaction-amount needed to be updated dynamically depending on users choices... So if anyone facing this, my workaround was to put it inside **updated()**, set an **id** to script tag and verify if **id** exists. Existing, I remove by id and all **.mercadopago-button**. PS: I'm newbie on JS and Vue.

```
let existingScript = document.getElementById('mpScript');
let existingButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('mercadopago-button');
if(existingScript) {
  existingScript.remove();
  while(existingButtons.length > 0) {
    existingButtons[0].parentNode.removeChild(existingButtons[0]);
  }
}

let script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("src", "https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js");
script.setAttribute("data-transaction-amount", this.total);
script.setAttribute("data-public-key", 'KEY');
script.setAttribute("id", "mpScript");
this.$refs.mpCheckout.appendChild(script);
```